# Invariant Violation: Missing parameter for path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a path `/me` with subpath `:subcategory`. In my handler's logic, when the prop `subcategory` is not set a default content should be displayed however, upon using the url `/me` I get this error: *Invariant Violation: Missing "subcategory" parameter for path "/me/:subcategory"*

```
<Route path="me">
  <Route handler={Me} name="me" path=":subcategory" />
</Route>
```

What am I doing wrong? Specifying the handler for both Routes didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought there is something wrong with my `<Route>` definition, so, after a needlessly long research through the internet, because there really is no information about this *easily* found, I have found out that the Routes are correct and that there are two solutions to this.

1. ALL Links **require** parameters to be set *(nope, `null` won't work, you silly programmer)*
   before: `<Link to='me'>Me</Link>`
   after: `<Link params={{subcategory: 'app'}} to='me'>Me</Link>`
2. Make the subpath optional -> add `?`
   `<Route handler={Me} name="me" path=":subcategory?" />`

Advantage of the second approach is that it is not necessary to find and refactor ALL older links, just the logic of the handler.